# Rudin's RCA The Open Mapping Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

There is the definition which we need for the theorem:
[image]

This is the Baire's theorem:

If $X$ is a complete metric space, the intersection of every coutanble collection of dense open subsets of $X$ is dense in $X$ .

[image]

I don't understand how does the Baire theorem imply that

there is a nonempty open set $W$ in the closure of some $\Lambda(kU)$.

I also don't understand how does the linearity of $\Lambda$ shows that the last inequality holds  if $\delta$ $=$ $\frac {\tau}{2k}$ ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, the Baire theorem is written like this:

> If $X$ is complete, then the intersection of a countable collection of dense open subsets of $X$ is dense in $X$.

But you can also write the Baire theorem like this:

> If $X$ is complete, then the union of a countable collection of closed subsets of $X$ with empty interior has empty interior.

To see that the two statements are equivalent, simply observe that:

- A set is open iff its complement is closed.
- A set is dense iff its complement has empty interior.

In your proof, the $\overline{\Lambda(k U)}$'s are a countable collection of closed subsets of $Y$, and $Y$ is a complete metric space. The union of the $\overline{\Lambda(k U)}$'s is the whole of $Y$, and so, the union of the $\overline{\Lambda(k U)}$'s certainly cannot have empty interior. Therefore, at least one of the $\overline{\Lambda(k U)}$'s has non-empty interior - which is to say that some $\overline{\Lambda(k U)}$ contains a non-empty open set $W$.

---

Regarding your second question, we know that for all $y$ such that $\left\| y \right\| < \eta $, there exists a sequence $\{ x_i \}$ with $\left\| x_i \right\| < 2k $ such that $\Lambda x_i \to y$.

Said another way, for all $y$ such that $\left\| y \right\| < \eta $ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $x$ with $\left\| x \right\| < 2k $ such that $\left\| \Lambda x - y \right\| < \epsilon $.

Let's now prove an alternative version of the above statement, with one of the $<$ symbols replaced by $\leq$ symbols. Let's prove that for all $y$ such that $\left\| y \right\| \leq \eta $ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $x$ with $\left\| x \right\| < 2k $ such that $\left\| \Lambda x - y \right\| < \epsilon $.

To prove this, observe that there exists a $\tilde y$ with $\| \tilde y \| < \eta$ and $\| \tilde y - y \| < \tfrac 1 2 \epsilon$. (For example, take $\tilde y = (1 - \min(\tfrac 1 4 \epsilon / \| y \|, \tfrac 1 2) ) y$.) We know that there exists an $x$ with $\left\| x \right\| < 2k $ such that $\left\| \Lambda x - \tilde y \right\| < \tfrac 1 2 \epsilon $. So $\left\| \Lambda x - y \right\| \leq \left\| \Lambda x - \tilde y \right\| + \left\| \tilde y - y \right\| < \epsilon$.

Now consider a general $y$, and pick a $\delta > 0$. Fix an $\epsilon > 0$. Define $y' = (\eta / \left\| y \right\|) y $. We have $\left\| y' \right\| \leq \eta$. So the statement a couple of paragraphs earlier applies to $y'$. Applying this statement with $\epsilon ' = \epsilon \eta /\left\| y \right\|$, we find that there exists an $x'$ with $\left\| x' \right\| < 2k $ such that $\left\| \Lambda x' - y' \right\| < \epsilon ' = \epsilon \eta /\left\| y \right\|  $.

Define $x = (\left\| y \right\| / \eta)  x' $. We have $\left\| x \right\| \leq 2k \left\| y \right\| / \eta = \delta^{-1}\left\| y \right\| $. Furthermore, since $\Lambda$ is linear, we have $\Lambda x = (\left\| y \right\| / \eta) \Lambda x' $. Thus $\| \Lambda x - y \|  = (\left\| y \right\| / \eta) \| \Lambda x' - y' \| < \epsilon $, which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Why do we have ||$y’$|| $\lt$ $\eta$? @Kenny Wong

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't careful enough with $<$ versus $\leq$. I've edited. Please take another look.

Comment: I don't understand why did you take $\tilde y = (1 - \min(\tfrac 1 4 \epsilon / \| y \|, \tfrac 1 2) ) y$.)

Comment: Firstly, observe that $0 < 1 - \min(\tfrac 1 4 \epsilon / \| y \|, \tfrac 1 2) < 1$. This implies that $\| \tilde y \| < \| y \|$. So if $\| y \| \leq \eta$, then $\| \tilde y \| < \eta$.

Comment: Secondly, observe that $1 - (1 - \min(\tfrac 1 4 \epsilon / \| y \|, \tfrac 1 2) ) < \tfrac 1 2 \epsilon / \| y \|$. So $\| y - \tilde y \| < \tfrac 1 2 \epsilon$.

Comment: why this implies that ||$\tilde y $|| $\lt$  $||y||$ ?

Comment: If $y$ is a non-zero vector and $\alpha$ is a number between $0$ and $1$, then $\| \alpha y\| < \| y \|$.

Comment: So what? Do we know that $||y||$ $\lt$ $1$?

Comment: We don't need $\left\| y \right| < 1$. We need $\alpha < 1$. Here, $\alpha = (1 - \min(\tfrac 1 4 \epsilon / \| y \|, \tfrac 1 2) )$.

Comment: Look - forget about that formula for $\tilde y$. All I'm saying is the following: If you give me a non-zero vector $y$, then by shrinking $y$ a little bit while preserving its direction, I can construct a new vector $\tilde y$ whose norm is smaller than the norm of $y$, and which lies within a distance $\epsilon$ of $y$. Do you agree with this? Can you visualise this?

Comment: In fact, do you visualise the arguments in Rudin? It's almost impossible to make sense of the proofs in Rudin without visualising what's going on geometrically. This whole argument is very intuitive when you visualise it, which is why Rudin completely glossed over it. Writing out a step-by-step algebraic proof and checking it line by line is much harder than just visualising the thing.

Comment: @KennyWong Can you please clarify? Given that ${x=(\left\Vert y\right\Vert /\eta)x'}$ and ${\left\Vert x'\right\Vert <2k}$, how do we get the following: ${\left\Vert x\right\Vert \leq2k\left\Vert y\right\Vert /\eta=\delta^{-1}\left\Vert y\right\Vert }$? It seems that this has to do with the possibility that limit points of $$ are also mapped to $Y$ due to the continuity of $\Lambda$ and the closure of $\Lambda\left(kU\right)$ on the $$ side. But can you please clarify and elaborate if necessary?